# VBA Clean use of many Constants

Tags: vba, excel

My Excel VBA takes ~300 XLS files and grabs 8 cells to deposit into their own row. (Office11)  I have several subs and functions that use location constants for the sourceData and destination locations.  Grand Total I have 23 constant locations with Column numbers, cell locations.

Question:  Any suggestions on how to clean this up for readability and keeping constants all in one location?  I was trying to avoid public variables but not sure of a better method.  How do you do Arrays containing constant values?

partial example,
`Public pstrQLocations(1 To 8) As String 

    pstrQLocations(1) = "B7" 

    pstrQLocations(2) = "B6"

    pstrQLocations(3) = "B5"

    pstrQLocations(4) = "B8"

    pstrQLocations(5) = "A3"

    pstrQLocations(6) = "C8"`

Comment: Wouldn't that be a use case for named ranges?

Comment: How would named ranges work for both the (many source) and the single destination workbooks?  The Destination workbook is where the VBA code is contained.

Comment: This makes sense for thisWorkbook (with the VBA code) using the following.  However, this seams illogical to use named ranges for 300 external files. ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SomeName", _
    RefersTo:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your Constants in a `Collection`. The advantage is, that you can give your elements names.

```
Option Explicit
Dim pstrQLocations As Collection

Private Sub initializeConstants()
    Set pstrQLocations = New Collection

    pstrQLocations.Add "B7", "Title"
    pstrQLocations.Add "B6", "User"
End Sub

Private Sub showConstants()
    initializeConstants
    Debug.Print Me.Range(pstrQLocations("Title")).Value
    Debug.Print Me.Range(pstrQLocations("User")).Value
End Sub
```

3D Version:

```
Option Explicit
Dim pstrQLocations As Collection

Private Sub initializeConstants()
    Dim title As New Collection

    Set pstrQLocations = New Collection

    title.Add "B7", "source"
    title.Add "A6", "destination"

    pstrQLocations.Add title, "Title"
End Sub

Private Sub showConstants()
    Dim y As Collection
    initializeConstants

    Debug.Print pstrQLocations("Title")("source")
    Debug.Print pstrQLocations("Title")("destination")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, may I make that Collection 3D?  i.e. *.Add "B7", "Title", "A6" so it lets me store [source location, name, destination location]

Comment: I added a 3D version and fixed the 2D one.